# How to get normal value from IO action in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I have the following function:

```
get :: Chars -> IO Chars
get cs = do
    char <- getChar
    let (dats, idx) = (curData cs, curIndex cs)
    let (x,y:xs) = splitAt idx dats
    let replacement = x ++ (ord char) : xs
    return $ Chars replacement idx
```

and I'd like to get a `Chars` value out of it, *not* an `IO` action. I have *no* idea how to do this, or if it is even possible.

The `Chars` type is basically just a container:

```
data Chars = Chars {
               curData  :: [Int],
               curIndex :: Int
               -- etc.
             }
```

The specifics aren't that important, I just want to know if there's a way for this function to return a `Chars` instead of an `IO Chars`.

If not, how do I pass this as an argument to a function that takes a `Chars`? I'm kind of new to Haskell I/O, but I don't think I want all of my functions that take `Chars` as arguments to instead have to take `IO Chars` as arguments, and then extract and repackage them. It seems unnecessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Do we not have a canonical "How do I get an `a` out of an `IO a`?" question to mark this a duplicate of yet?

Comment: It isn't canonical (being marked as a duplicate itself), but it's title and age would make it a suitable candidate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16773528 .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't, because that would violate [referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29).

IO in Haskell is made this way exactly to distinguish between actions whose result and effects may vary depending on the interaction with the environment/user and pure functions whose results are not going to change when you call them with the same input parameters.

In order to pass the result to a pure function taking a `Chars` in input you have to call your IO action into another IO action, bind the result with the `<-` operator to a variable and pass it to your pure function. Pseudocode example:

```
myPureFunction :: Chars -> ...

otherAction :: Chars -> IO ()
otherAction cs = do
  myChars <- get cs
  let pureResult = myPureFunction myChars
  ...
```

If you're new to IO in haskell, you may wish to have a look at the Input and Output chapters in [Learn You a Haskell for a Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html).

There is actually a way to simply get a pure value out of an IO action, but in your case you shouldn't do it, as you're interacting with the environment: the unsafe way is ok only when you can guarantee you're not violating referential transparency.

Comment: Thank you! I think this makes sense now. I've read all of LYAH, but it's been a while since I've done anything with IO so I wasn't sure exactly how to handle this.

So, I have a few functions that take a `Chars` and return a `Chars` but don't touch IO. Should I modify those to return an `IO Chars` just for the sake of simplicity? I'm hesitant to change everything around like that, but the program should theoretically still work given that's the case.

Comment: No, you shouldn't give up on referential transparency guaranteed by the types when you can. So let those functions be, do not make them return something like `IO a`.

Answer (score 12):

It's impossible (I lie, there is an extremely unsafe way to cheat your way out of it).

The point is that if any I/O is performed, the behaviour and result of your programme may not depend only on explicit arguments to the used functions, thus that must be declared in the type by having it `IO something`.

You use the result of an `IO a` action in a pure function by binding the result in `main` (or something called from `main`) and then applying the pure function, binding the result in a `let`,

```
cs ::Chars
cs = undefined

main = do
  chars <- get cs
  let result = pureFunction chars
  print result
```

or, if the function you want to apply to `chars` has type `Chars -> IO b`

```
main = do
    chars <- get cs
    doSomething chars
```