# Haskell: Turtle: Managing Shell type

Tags: shell, haskell, tree-traversal, io-monad, haskell-turtle

This a working snippet:

```
import Turtle
...
groom :: FilePath -> IO ()
groom src = do
  view (ls src)
...
```

I can see a list of paths on the console. Actually I'd like to have something like `[FilePath]` for use, e.g.:

```
treeCount :: FilePath -> Int
treeCount src = length (lstree src)
```

Naturally, it won't compile, `lstree` being what it is:

```
lstree :: FilePath -> Shell FilePath
```

What is the correct way to treat this `Shell` thing? It's a newbie question, sorry.

Comment: What is `Turtle`?

Comment: What is the type of `length`?

Comment: @melpomene https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle it seems

Comment: Right you are, The Aspiring Hacker.

Comment: `length :: t a -> Int`; used mainly on lists. Pretty polymorphic, but not enough for `Shell FilePath` :)

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.5/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:sort looks close.

Comment: Does `length` have typeclass constraints? Which package is it from?

Comment: `length` is from `Data.Foldable`, it's one of the bedrock tools. It's beside the point, though. One has understand `Shell` to solve this problem. I've no idea so far.

Comment: I just looked. `Shell` has to implement `Foldable`, then.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.5/docs/Turtle-Shell.html# says it has `IO a -> Shell a`, so it can't possibly be `Foldable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this, but just looking at the type signatures the following might work:

```
import qualified Control.Foldl as F

treeCount :: FilePath -> IO Int
treeCount src = fold (lstree src) F.length
```

Fold with `F.list` to get `[FilePath]` instead.

Comment: Couldn't match expected type ‘Shell FilePath
                                    -> Fold a1 Int -> Int’
                  with actual type ‘Fold a0 [a0]’
    • The function ‘F.list’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘Fold a0 [a0]’ has none
      In the expression: F.list (lstree src) F.length
      In an equation for ‘treeCount’:
          `treeCount src = F.list (lstree src) F.length`

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov That needs to be `fold (lstree src) F.list`.

Comment: No instance for (MonadIO []) arising from a use of ‘fold’

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov Did you give it the wrong type signature? It should return `IO [FilePath]`.

Comment: It compiles, thanks! I'm taking a timeout: I have to grok it.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov I'm not familiar with Shell, but there seems to be a lot going on here. `Shell` is a monad, where `Shell a` stands for a stream of `a` values, each produced with a side effect. The library provides functions like `Turtle.Shell.fold` to "convert" a `Shell` computation into an `IO` one, as long as a folding function is provided to "compress" the stream into a single value (e.g. `F.length` above).

Comment: Thanks again! I'm falling behind, though. I hope for tomorrow.

Comment: I am not the first one to be trapped by IO monad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467066/how-to-get-normal-value-from-io-action-in-haskell

Comment: There is even an icon: https://photos.smugmug.com/Humor/Lambdacats/trapd-in-IO-monad-plz-help/960526421_MnNqB-S-1.jpg