# How do I get a list of Strings containing file names in the current directory?

Tags: haskell

I need the list for further operations on strings. I do not want just print the list of strings!

### my code so far

https://gist.github.com/bigos/0067a62e15dbed264ce6ef92e0eca58c

### clarification of my goal

I would consider the question answered if somebody provided an example where code traverses through the list of filenames and prints the first half of each filename.

### explanation why I could not do it

This question
[How to get normal value from IO action in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467066/how-to-get-normal-value-from-io-action-in-haskell)
has the answer submitted by Riccardo T.

has nice pseudocode example.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes.

Comment: You've probably got downvote and close because you didn't included code inside the question only link to gist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `(=<<) :: ([String] -> IO b) -> (IO [String] -> IO b)` to teach a function which expects lists of strings how to handle a value like `listDirectory "."` that produces IO-wrapped lists of strings instead. In idiomatic Haskell, its `flip`ped form, `(>>=) :: IO [String] -> ([String] -> IO b) -> IO b`, is more common, because its arguments appear in the order that IO is executed. So, for example:

```
import System.Directory

printFirstHalfOfSingleString :: String -> IO ()
printFirstHalfOfSingleString s = putStrLn (take (length s `div` 2) s)

printFirstHalfOfEachString :: [String] -> IO ()
printFirstHalfOfEachString = mapM_ printFirstHalfOfSingleString

main = listDirectory "." >>= printFirstHalfOfEachString
```

Comment: My mistake was trying to pass the second argument to mapM_  like this: mapM_ printFirstHalfOfSingleString (listDirectory ".")

Comment: @ruby_object Why not just say that in your question? If you'd posted that code, you'd've probably gotten an answer much quicker.

Comment: In Haskell part of the problem is knowing what question to ask. After failure after failure and not knowing how to read the error messages I just fell back to a standard imperative question I would ask in that situation.

Comment: my version using =<< operator.  mapM_ (\l -> putStrLn l) =<< listDirectory "."

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for 
[getDirectoryContents](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.3.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v:getDirectoryContents), the equivalent of `ls` in shell ?

Here is a program that lists the file names below the current working directory, printing half of each :

```
import System.Directory

firstHalf :: String -> String
firstHalf s = take (length s `div` 2) s

main = do
    -- Get the current working directory
    current <- getCurrentDirectory
    -- Lists the file in current
    children <- getDirectoryContents current
    mapM putStrLn (map firstHalf children)
```

In your [gist](https://gist.github.com/bigos/0067a62e15dbed264ce6ef92e0eca58c) code, try `listDirectory = getDirectoryContents` and
take care, `getDirectoryContents` result also contains `"."` and `".."`

Comment: trying to write own ls would be a step towards achieving what I want. I guess part of the problem is that I do not understand how function arguments work in Haskell.