# How To Properly Choose Which USB Device To Connect To?

Tags: haskell

I am new to both USB drivers and Haskell. I am trying to connect to Tomu (an ARM micocontroller that fits in a USB port) using System.USB. I tried this example: https://github.com/basvandijk/usb-example/blob/master/example.hs, but it is several years out of date. I am trying to do hello world on USB, but getting type errors.

The following code works:

```
module Lib where

import System.USB
import System.USB.IO
import Data.Vector 
import Data.Maybe

getOneDesc :: Int -> IO (VendorId, ProductId) 
getOneDesc n = do
    usbConn <- newCtx
    devList <- getDevices usbConn
    f <- getDeviceDesc $ devList ! n
    let f0 = deviceVendorId f
    let f1 = deviceProductId f
    return (f0, f1)
```

At the repl, I can type getOneDesc 0 and I get something like this:

```
(300, 42)
```

I figured I ought to be able to do something like this:

```
isThisDeviceTheOneIWant :: Int -> VendorId -> ProductId -> Bool
isThisDeviceTheOneIWant n a b = do
    (x, y) <- getOneDesc n
    return (x == a) && (y == b)
```

But I encounter type errors.

Can anybody see what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `getOneDesc` is an `IO (VendorId, ProductId)`, so that means that the result type of your `return (x == a) && (y == b)` has type `IO Bool`. So you should change the type of your function. You must also add parentheses around the argument you pass to `return` (because in Haskell, `return` is not a keyword, just a plain function).

```
isThisDeviceTheOneIWant :: Int -> VendorId -> ProductId -> IO Bool
isThisDeviceTheOneIWant n a b = do
    (x, y) <- getOneDesc n
    return ((x == a) && (y == b))
```

You can not make the `isThisDeviceTheOneIWant` return a `Bool`, since the `getOneDesc`  returns an `IO (VendorId, ProductId)`, and you can [*not* get an `a` out of an `IO a`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11467066/67579).

We can, like [@DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193747/how-to-properly-choose-which-usb-device-to-connect-to/56193769?noredirect=1#comment99012752_56193769) says, use [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) to process the result of the `getOneDesc n`, like:

```
isThisDeviceTheOneIWant :: Int -> VendorId -> ProductId -> IO Bool
isThisDeviceTheOneIWant n a b = fmap ((a, b) ==) (getOneDesc n)
```

or use [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) which is the same as `fmap`:

```
isThisDeviceTheOneIWant :: Int -> VendorId -> ProductId -> IO Bool
isThisDeviceTheOneIWant n a b = ((a, b) ==) <$> getOneDesc n
```

Comment: And if you want to get fancy, you could write `isThisDeviceTheOneIWant n a b = ((a,b)==) <$> getOneDesc n`. I recommend this for the expert, so that readers need not double-check for something sneaky going on in this otherwise simple `do` block; but for a beginner it might be a bit much.