# Haskell IO String -> String

Tags: haskell

I have the following function:

```
getBoard :: String
getBoard = do
    contents <- readFile "src/board.txt"
    return contents
```

and I'm getting this error:

• Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
Expected type: [String]
Actual type: IO String

Already read a lot of things on the internet, and apparently my code should work. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Obs: When I go to repl and do:

```
contents <- readFile "src/board.txt"
```

and then:

```
:type contents
```

It says to me that contents is a String. So, I can't figure out why I'm getting the error I put above.

**Note: The getBoard function MUST return a String**

Comment: You could also ask the repl for the type of `return`. In Haskell, `return` is just a function. Its type is: `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`. Now the question is: which monad did you want or expect ?

Comment: What you are saying is that I need to have another function of type IO String -> String ?

Comment: @ThallesPortilho the type system will not let you do arbitrary side effects in a function: "The getBoard function MUST return a String" it literally *can't*. Or to put it differently, if you want a function to return a plain string it can't read it from a file (or STDIN, or...).

Comment: @ThallesPortilho Well, a polymorphic function of type `IO a -> a` exists in the library. Hoogle will happily point you to it, this is [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO). But the clue is in the name. If you use for example `getLine` thru `unsafePerformIO`, you will always read the same line, because of *referential transparency*. Details in the [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467066/how-to-get-normal-value-from-io-action-in-haskell) pointed to by the person who closed your question

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056867 .

Answer (score 2):

You've written:

```
getBoard :: String
```

That doesn't say that `getBoard` is a function or procedure that returns a `String`.  Rather, it says that `getBoard` **is** a `String`; I mean some specific `String` like `"Hello world"` or `"foo"`, for example.  Obviously, that's wrong.  Rather, `getBoard` is a procedure you can perform that produces a `String` as its result.  In Haskell, the way you say that is:

```
getBoard :: IO String
```

So that's the right answer.  If that answer doesn't work for you, please provide more context so we can understand why.

When you say "Note: The getBoard function MUST return a String", that's almost exactly what `getBoard :: IO String` means: `getBoard` is a procedure that returns a `String`.  (One subtle point here is that I've said "procedure" instead of "function".  That's because in Haskell, "function" means something different from what you're probably expecting from other languages.  A function is something that takes parameters.  Because `getBoard` doesn't take parameters, it's not a function, but it **is** a procedure.)

Did you mean that you want it to **be** a `String`, rather than return one?  This doesn't make much sense, though.  Which specific `String` would you like it to be?

---

Okay, now is where I reluctantly admit that there is one way to tell Haskell (incorrectly) that `getBoard` is a `String`.  You shouldn't do this unless you're a pretty advanced Haskell programmer, understand the implications, and have a good reason it's worth it.  But you can import `System.IO.Unsafe` and then wrap the definition of `getBounds` with the `unsafePerformIO` function.  What this says is: "Pretend that `getBounds` is some specific `String` rather than a procedure.  Any time you need to know which `String` it is, go sneak off behind the scenes and run this procedure to find out."

Note that if you do this, there is NO guarantee about when your program will read the file, how many times your program will read the file, or even whether your program will read the file at all!  All of these things can depend on things like strictness of evaluation, which optimization choices like inlining the compiler makes, and so on.  If the contents of the file change while your program is running, the result is undefined.  This is **not** a normal way to write Haskell, other Haskell programmers will give you weird looks and assume you're kind of clueless if you do it without a good reason, and you should probably just forget about it until you're more on the advanced side.  I only mentioned it because I don't want to give an incomplete response.